# Why pdfTeX gives different results with identical typesetting instructions?

Tags: pdftex

I noticed strange behavior in pdfTeX and do not understand how to explain it. In the following two examples pdf files look differently.
`texlive-lang-czechslovak` package must be installed to try these examples. I also attach here the pdf files which I generated: [example1.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j502d464rt557lb/bad_letter_e-1.pdf?dl=0), [example2.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm81qy4lsd16blf/bad_letter_e-2.pdf?dl=0).

**Example1**

```
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\global\let\shipout\oldshipout\afterassignment\myboat\setbox255=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\showbox255\shipout\box255}
\nonstopmode
\let\originput\input
\def\input utf8off {\let\clearmubyte\empty \let\input\originput}
\originput docby.tex
\let\originput\undefined
\def\Black{\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}}
\let\Green\Black
\hsize=210mm\advance\hsize by-3cm
\def\outputhook{\hoffset=\ifodd\pageno1.5cm\else1.5cm\fi\advance\hoffset by-1in}
\def\ins #1{\ifirst {#1}{^^73udo}{\end}{++}}
\let\isnameprinted-

\parindent=20pt
\indent\llap{\hskip-\parindent\bf1.\hfill}Test.
\ins \jobname

\bye
sudo perl -i -pe "s/datestyle = 'iso, mdy'/datestyle = 'iso, ymd'/" /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf \
&& sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

**Example2**

```
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\global\let\shipout\oldshipout\afterassignment\myboat\setbox255=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\showbox255\shipout\box255}
\nonstopmode
\let\mubyte=\undefined \let\mubytein=\undefined
\input docby.tex
\def\Black{\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}}
\hsize=210mm\advance\hsize by-3cm
\def\outputhook{\hoffset=\ifodd\pageno1.5cm\else1.5cm\fi\advance\hoffset by-1in}
\def\ins #1{\ifirst {#1}{^^73udo}{\end}{++}}
\let\isnameprinted-

\parindent=20pt
\indent\llap{\hskip-\parindent\bf1.\hfill}Test.
\ins \jobname

\bye



sudo perl -i -pe "s/datestyle = 'iso, mdy'/datestyle = 'iso, ymd'/" /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf \
&& sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ pdfcsplain bad_letter_e-1.tex
$ pdfcsplain bad_letter_e-2.tex
$ pdftoppm bad_letter_e-1.pdf e1
$ pdftoppm bad_letter_e-2.pdf e2
$ md5sum e1-1.ppm e2-1.ppm
b08f8cd73e037280f8cdef7057c0e1a9  e1-1.ppm
a5818433399c443ad9fee8deb35208d9  e2-1.ppm
```

We see that the hashsum is different.
If we open these pdf files in pdf viewer, zoom to 400% and
compare them, we will see that letter "e" in word "postgresql.conf" is
shifted.

The above two examples use the same typesetting instructions, as can be seen from `\showbox` output.

This is the difference of `\showbox`:

```
--- bad_letter_e-1.log
+++ bad_letter_e-2.log
@@ -145,7 +145,6 @@
 ...\ttsmall s
 ...\ttsmall q
 ...\ttsmall l
-...\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}
 ...\ttsmall /
 ...\ttsmall *
 ...\ttsmall /
```

So, `\pdfliteral` influences typesetting? Is it the proper behavior?
If `\pdfliteral` is not the cause, how else can this be explained?

Comment: The hash differences may be due to different time stamps.  In your dropbox .pdf files I can not see the difference you mention in the typesetting at any zoom level.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: please run `pdftoppm` on my files from dropbox and write which hash sums you get from the resulting images.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue depends on external conversion applications/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Poppler pdf rendering library is to blame - pdf files themselves are OK. This may be checked by first converting `pdf` to `ps`, and then `ps` to image:

```
$ pdf2ps bad_letter_e-1.pdf
$ pdf2ps bad_letter_e-2.pdf
$ pstopnm bad_letter_e-1.ps
$ pstopnm bad_letter_e-2.ps
$ md5sum bad_letter_e-1*.ppm bad_letter_e-2*.ppm
a879acaaab2af4bd4a3c8563ec0c7c48  bad_letter_e-1001.ppm
a879acaaab2af4bd4a3c8563ec0c7c48  bad_letter_e-2001.ppm
```

Now hash sums are equal.